# left join on MS SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, left-join

I'm trying to left join two tables. Table A contains unique 100 records with `field_a_1`, `field_a_2`, `field_a_3`. The combination of `field_a_1` and `field_a_2` is unique.

Table B has multi-million records with multiple fields. `field_b_1` is same as `field_a_1` and `field_b_2` is same as `field_a_2`.

I join the two tables together like this:

```
select a.*, b.* 
from a 
left join b 
 on field_a_1 = field_b_1 
and field_a_2 = field_b_2
```

Instead of getting 100 records, I get multi-million records. Why is this?

Comment: I think you mean to inner join the tables.

Answer (score 4):

Because table B has multiple rows for each table A entry.

For example:

```
TableA (ID)
1
2
3    

TableB (ID, data)
1 hello
1 world
1 foo
1 bar
2 data
2 words
2 more 
3 words
3 boring
```

If you `left join` from TableA to TableB, you will get a row for every TableB record that matches a TableA record - ie. all of them.

Can you explain what results you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Because a left join returns all of the rows from the first table + all of the matching rows from the second table.  Which of the millions of matching rows did you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

Left join or inner join don't really make a difference. A JOIN will return all rows that match the join condition. So if table b has millions of rows that match the JOIN criteria, then all the rows will be returned.

Depending on what you wish to accomplish you should consider using the DISTINCT keyword or GROUP BY to perform aggregate functions.